# Driving LCD backlight using boost converter (Feedback loop & Constant Current)

Tags: circuit-design, voltage-regulator, lcd, constant-current, backlight

I've been researching LCD backlight circuits (for my STM32-based project), asked questions before, but there is another question I have about the matter.

I have noticed that some boost converters (I usually search for parts on mouser.de) explicitly propose an alternative configuration to drive LEDs with constant current. And it looks really genius.

This is not the chip I'm using, I'm talking specifically about the feedback loop and this is a good example I quickly googled up:

[image]

So, given that feedback pin voltage is a constant (usually 1.24V or close to it), I will basically force the chip to "generate whatever voltage is necessary so that the voltage on FB pin is 1.24V" (as long as the output voltage is within the spec, of course), and then it means that Rsense basically sets the current (1.24V/Rsense). So effectively I get a constant current LED driver, whose enable pin I can PWM all day to set LCD brightness.

Now, many of those boost converters understandably have soft start. I want to be sure it will cause no trouble. (and from the datasheets I read, most backlight PWM on EN/Shutdown pin are like 200Hz-1kHz and soft start is usually a pair of ms). I think it should work, rough estimate in my head suggests that soft start is still quick enough for low frequency PWM, wanna be sure there will be no unexpected side effect or something I didn't take into account.

From what I understand, I should have: a boost IC with EN from MCU timer pin, output of the IC goes straight into backlight LED Anode pin (+), then out of LED Cathode pin (-) the trace splits and goes into Rsense to GND and to feedback pin of the IC (pretty much like in picture duh).

In my design I'll use some simpler IC, the question is about the principle. Do I understand the whole thing correctly? Anything I should watch out for? Anything I understood wrong or forgot?

Comment: All the parts I have used for LED drive have an 'open device' detector to prevent the voltage at Vout going to dangerously high (for the part) voltages.

Comment: I'm sorry, does your comment have any relevance to my question? What are you even talking about? And my highest voltage will be like 12V anyway